# Applescript/Automator - stop a loop after given number of repetitions?

Tags: loops, applescript, automator

I have a looping Automator workflow that in its first step runs an Applescript that creates a list with N posts. N varies between executions of this workflow. I want the workflow to exit efter N repetitions. The problem is that the loop component in Automator doesn't take any input: the only options offered are "run the loop for a static, predefined, number of times" or "ask the user for each loop if (s)he wants to continue".

Currently I need to pass a parameter around with the number of repetitions ran as well as desired and then check if these number match. If the numbers match, I execute the following code:

`tell me to quit` (which is a pain when testing if you forget to disable it since it quits Automator itself).

Not very elegant. Are there better ways?

Answer (score 1):

If that's the only limited feature set of a "Loop" action (and it seems to be), then you're better off using loop control in AppleScript itself. Since you say you're using an AppleScript action, just add user input to get the number and use a repeat loop block (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-127362)

Here's a simple way to ensure number input:

```
set weHaveNumber to false
set defaultNumberText to "5"
set numberReturned to 0

repeat until weHaveNumber
    set q to display dialog "Enter number of loops:" default answer defaultNumberText buttons {"OK"} default button 1
    try
        if (text returned of q) is "" then error --this is here because empty string can be coerced to zero
        set numberReturned to text returned of q as integer
        set weHaveNumber to true
    on error e
        --
    end try
end repeat

--now use numberReturned, an integer, in your repeat loop
```